# How to efficiently interleave bits from 8 __int16 numbers?

Tags: c, interleave, z-order-curve

I am building Morton number for spatial indexing, I have 8 unsigned 16 bit numbers that will turn into __int128 number. The efficiency is crucial, so naive solution (loop over everything) or building separate 8 128bit numbers is too expensive.

I am using GCC, the target machine is 64 bits but without BMI2 support.

How can I speed up the computation?

Comment: [This](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#shuffle) may be of some interest.

Comment: @MatteoItalia thank you. Yes, I am aware of that, unfortunately by no BMI2 I do not have PDEP or PEXT instructions and am looking for calculating more codes at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your machine is x86 and supports SSE2, there is a clever answer using `movmsk` instructions. Google `SSE2 bit matrix transpose` for full code.

Comment: Yes, it does, x86_64. That is one clever idea. I'll wait for a while and then accept if nothing faster shows up. I assume [this SSE2 code](https://github.com/mischasan/sse2) is yours? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I am posting from a phone hence redirecting to the article. The code would be performant even for your narrow "matrix".